# Thread for every file in SFTP

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, sftp

I read files in SFTP server and make some process, the problem is my code run file by file and every file take from 4 to 6 hours, Can i run every file at the same time using thread?

This is My code inside a function

```
        sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            sftpChannel.cd("/upload");
            Vector filelist = sftpChannel.ls("/upload/test");
            List<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String fileName = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < filelist.size(); i++) {
                ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry = (ChannelSftp.LsEntry) filelist.get(i);
                if (entry.getFilename().startsWith("test")) {
                    fileName = entry.getFilename();
                    fileNameList.add(fileName);
                }

            }
            if (fileNameList != null && !fileNameList.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < fileNameList.size(); i++) {
                    fileSFTP = sftpChannel.get("/upload/test/" + fileNameList.get(i));
                    renamedFile = fileNameList.get(i);

                    // Open the file
                    String filename = "OTL";
                    File file = File.createTempFile(filename, ".zip");

                    // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
                    outputStream
                            = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    int read = 0;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[2056];

                    while ((read = fileSFTP.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }

                    if (file == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);

                    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                    itemObj = (Message) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                    buildJsonRequest(itemObj);
                    sftpChannel.rename("/upload/test/" + renamedFile,
                            "/upload/Loaded Test/" + renamedFile);
                    sftpChannel.cd("/upload/");
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Why couldn't you? But I have a hard time understanding how copying a file from an SFTP server to the local drive can take 4 to 6 hours. Are they so huge? If it's the disk or the network that slows you down, multi-threading probably won't bring any advantage though.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Yes the data is huge in each file, what is the best way to handle this issues? @JBNizet

Comment: It depends on what the performance bottleneck is.  Is it local disk?  Local network speed? Remote server disk?  Remote server network?  Your connection to your ISP?  Are you retrieving the file from a long way away?  Depending on the answers, using a *small* number of threads *might* help.  Or it might have minimal effect.

Comment: @StephenC is correct. When bandwidth or disk or whole CPU is the bottleneck, threads won't help. If network latency or CPU core performance is bottleneck, threads can help. See also https://serverfault.com/q/694062/168875